# Filter DataGridView Table by SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I am making a program in which a user can add a member to a data grid view, edit the members in that grid and delete members. I'm able to add members easily enough, but my problem arrives when I want to filter the DataGridView results (which default to all the data in a table named 'MembersTable') so that the user can edit specific data without having to search through the entire table results.

The following is the method in a class called 'MemberClass'

```
public static List<MemberClass> SearchMember(string MemberIdentifier)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring))
    {
        List<MemberClass> MemberList = new List<MemberClass>();

        //connection open
        connection.Open();

        string sqlQuery = string.Format("SELECT * FROM MembersTable WHERE MemberID = '{0}'", MemberIdentifier);

        SqlCommand searchForMember = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);

        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = searchForMember.ExecuteReader();

        while (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                MemberClass newMemberClass = new MemberClass((int)sqlDataReader["MemberID"], (string)sqlDataReader["FirstName"], (string)sqlDataReader["LastName"], (string)sqlDataReader["MemberAddress"], (string)sqlDataReader["TypeOfMembershipID"], (string)sqlDataReader["PhoneNumber"], (DateTime)sqlDataReader["MembershipStart"], (DateTime)sqlDataReader["MembershipEnd"], (string)sqlDataReader["Notice"], (string)sqlDataReader["TypeOfPaymentID"]);
                MemberList.Add(newMemberClass);
            }
    connection.Close();
    //connection close

    return MemberList;
}
```

In my Main Screen form I use the following code behind a button to search through the results based upon data (in this case the MemberID) entered by the user.

```
List <MemberClass> MemberList = MemberClass.SearchMember(textBox1.Text);
```

My question is, how do I filter the results of the DataGridView box to only display results filtered by the above code and the MemberID entered by the user?

Apologies for my ignorance, I'm relatively new to DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

When i need to filter my datagridview, i create a textBox under the columnheader.
Then, i catch the appropriate textBox.TextChanged event and i reload my datagridview with a second query, which is the default query with a WHERE clause.

This is my VB.NET code but it might help you to understand.

I use `dataBinding` :

```
Private WithEvents datasBindingSource As New BindingSource()
```

**txtChanged event :**

```
Private Sub txtfilterMemberID_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtfilterMemberID.TextChanged
    filterDatas()
End Sub
```

**Filter Sub :**

```
Private Sub filterDatas()
    ListObjets = _dao.YourQuery
    datasBindingSource.DataSource = ListObjets
    dtg.DataSource = datasBindingSource

    Dim query =
    From row In ListObjets
    Where row.MemberID.ToString.Contains(txtfilterMemberID.Text) 
    Select row

    If query.Count > 0 Then
        If ListObjets.Count = query.Count Then
            datasBindingSource.DataSource = ListObjets
        Else
            datasBindingSource.DataSource = query
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No data found !")
        If txtfilterMemberID.Focused = True Then
            txtfilterMemberID.ResetText()       
    End If
End Sub
```

Row.MemberID is the column that you need to filter.
The filterDatas method will loop through all your Datas and only display those containing the txtBox.Text value in the column.

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET to C#

```
 private void filterDatas()
{
    dynamic query = from row in ListObjets where row.id.ToString.Contains(txtBoxId.Text) select row;

    if (query.Count > 0)
    {
        if (ListObjets.Count == query.Count)
        {
            datasBindingSource.DataSource = ListObjets;
        }
        else {
            datasBindingSource.DataSource = query;
        }
    }
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("No data found!");
        if (txtBoxId.Focused == true)
        {
            txtBoxId.ResetText();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was able to retask this code to my own in almost every way with the exception of the part, "where row.id". What is 'id' in this context? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms I am using `bindingSource` and `SqlDataAdapter` to fill the table with all data.

Example:

```
SqlDataAdapter^ dataAdapter = gcnew SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM    table",connection);
        connection->Open();
        DataTable^ table = gcnew DataTable();
        dataAdapter->Fill(table);
        bindingSource->DataSource = table;
```

Then to filter i use `TextChanged` Event on `textbox` and `dateTimepicker` controller, you do not need to send another request to Database:

```
buildFilter = "";
filterBuilder(this->tName->Text,"`Name`");
bindingSource->Filter = buildFilter;
```

And the builder look like this:

```
void OverView::filterBuilder(String^ txt,String^ Column_name){
    if(!txt->Equals(""))
    {
        if(!buildFilter->Equals("")){
            buildFilter = buildFilter+ " AND ";
        }
        buildFilter = buildFilter + Column_name +" LIKE '*"+ txt + "*'";
    }
    buildFilter = buildFilter;
}
```

This Example filter grid by Name.

EDIT : 
And you also need to connect `bindingSource` with `DataGridView`.

```
dgView->DataSource = bindingSource;
```