# Is it possible to search a DataGridView or DataTable with SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview, datatable

I wonder if it's possible to use SQL query to search a DataGridView or DataTable.

I have a couple of columns and want to search for results with a given set of conditions (column a = x and column b < 3 for example). Or do I have to use a database for this?

Comment: Possible duplicated [Filter DataGridView Table by SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197212/filter-datagridview-table-by-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

You could use Linq queries on DataTable (would not recommend querying DataGrid)

```
DataTable orders = ds.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"];

// Query the SalesOrderHeader table for orders using linq
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
    where order.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate") > new DateTime(2001, 8, 1)
    select order;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing to linq. I planned to be able to create conditions at runtime, therefore I liked the idea of being able to just create some kind of SQL string on the fly depending on what kind of parameters the user selects. As far as I can see this kind of approach will be more difficult with linq, right?

Comment: @Henning no you cant use raw queries on generic objects, you can try to use ORM or Ado.net that takes raw queries and execute it accordingly when conditions change.

Comment: Phew that sounds complicated, at least since I am not a pro. Is there any way to work with some kind of "virtual" database so I can use sql queries? By virtual I mean not somewhere on the disk but in RAM only.

Comment: @Henning you could use switch case or conditional statements and execute the query to desired condition, but i think that would lead to inefficient, less readable spaghetti code.